# SQLite.swift causing Operator is not a known binary operator

Tags: swift, sqlite

in an iOS project I'm using [AlamofireObjectmapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) to make a rich model and in one of the methods I want to use [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) to save data locally. My problem is that when I do the import SQLite my mapping method starts to show some errors:

[image]

SQLite.swift is not Swift 3 ready and my project is using swift 3, so I had to get it from a branch. Here is the line of my podfile:

```
  pod 'SQLite.swift', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git',
    :branch => 'swift3-mariotaku'
```

Would you know how can I solve these errors?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I put the SQLite methods in a extension class, in another file

```
extension BeaconModel {
   // methods
}
```